# New Users not visible at login

Tags: login, users

I have created a couple of new users via the **Users and Groups** GUI for Ubuntu 16.04, however they are not available on the log in screen (nor log out/ switch user).

I used the same method on a virtual machine (as a test) and it worked.  I have googled and found no questions similar to mine so I have no idea where to go next.

I have not tried to create a user via the CLI.

Any suggestions as to why I cannot log in via the new user?

Thanks!

Comment: was the new user given a password after creation?

Comment: yes - this was just for testing, so I gave the users passwords

Comment: I add a user via the CLI - still not visible at login but is in Users and Groups.  It seems like something is hiding the users at log in but it's not in the the lightdm.conf as far as i can see.
Is there some other place that I may have disabled showing the users?  I am using Ubuntu 16.04 with Cinnamon desktop

Answer (score 0):

It was a Cinnamon Desktop thing.  I accidentally placed my mouse cursor over only visible user and a list showed up, allowing me to select a user.